# Reverse a list in haskell 3

Tags: haskell

#### example

- Input: `[1..10]`
- Output: `[1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6,6,5,7,4,8,3,9,2,10,1]`

I tried this

```
fon(x:y:xs) =reverse (x:xs)
fun (x:y:xs) = x : (fon xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

what about this:

```
interweave :: [a] -> [a]
interweave zs = f zs (reverse zs)
    where f xs ys = concat $ zipWith (\ x y -> [x,y]) xs ys
```

example

```
λ> interweave [1..10]
[1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6,6,5,7,4,8,3,9,2,10,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework, I'll provide a hint.

You need both the original list and the reversed list. Try something like

```
foo :: [a] -> [a]
foo xs = bar xs (reverse xs)

bar :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
...
```